# Problem installing Ubuntu - endless loading with logo

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I'm trying to install again Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows (I deleted  Ubuntu few weeks ago, canceling the corresponding partition and the Ubuntu folder in EFI), but as soon as I click *Try Ubuntu without installing* or *Install Ubuntu*, it does not work (endless loading) as in the screenshot. It is not a problem with the flash drive because on other laptops I'm able to start the installation.

[image]

Comment: What version Ubuntu? From memory... when booting the USB flash drive, as soon as you see a small keyboard icon at the bottom of the screen, hit (any?) key on the keyboard, then hit (F6?) and choose `nomodeset`, then continue the boot. I'm guessing that you're trying to install Ubuntu on an older computer, yes?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm trying to install on Asus Vivobook Pro N580GD-E4087T, bought a month ago :)

Comment: Did you try `nomodeset`? Also, since your computer is so new, can you please try 18.10?

Comment: @heynnema I tried nomodeset but nothing does change. Anyway, I tried Ubuntu 18.10, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Google `Asus Vivobook Pro N580GD-E4087T` and see if there's some special setting in the BIOS that needs tweaking for Linux/Ubuntu. Make sure you have the latest BIOS firmware installed.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402972